# The invocation of the constructor that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

When I am trying to create a new directory in my WPF application  i am getting the following error.

> " 'The invocation of the constructor on type
>   'NetworkApplication.Login' that matches the specified binding
>   constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position
>   '9'."

this is my line of code

```
DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\\Windows\\Newfolder1");
```

Comment: Run the application in VS debugger, set a breakpoint at that line, step over it and check the exception.

Comment: You can't create directories in the c:\windows directory.  Not unless you elevate rights for your program.  Don't do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force my .NET App to run as administrator on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 3):

Besides the security issues, you're trying to escape a string that has the @ in front of it.  Either remove the @ or un-escape the slashes.